Docker container on Postman error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
I'm running a Docker container like this:

When I call this endpoint on Postman, I get this error:

My Dockerfile.yml is like this:
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS base
    WORKDIR /app

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY . .

    RUN dotnet restore "CentralAPI/CentralServiceAPI.csproj"
    WORKDIR "/src/."
    COPY . .
    RUN dotnet build "CentralAPI/CentralServiceAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

    FROM build as publish
    RUN dotnet publish "CentralAPI/CentralServiceAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "CentralServiceAPI.dll" ]

I'm new to Docker. I tried disabling proxy in Postman settings and on Internet Options.
I also tried to ping the connection like this, the results:
# curl https://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

I'm using VS Code and I'm on Windows.
My API is running on port https://localhost:7102/ if launched with IIS.

It doesn't look like you're installing a (self-signed) cert anywhere as part of your setup. I suspect changing https to http will solve the immediate connectivity issue.
However, if you do want to use a TLS cert locally, you'll need to do some additional work. Something like this: https://www.labkey.org/Documentation/wiki-page.view?name=dockerTLS

Using http comes "Error: socket hang up". I will check that link though. Thanks.

Seems like that TLS configs are for Linux, I'm on Windows
